# CMake: how to break a PRE_LINK infinite loop?

Tags: loops, cmake, dependencies, prelink

I'm trying to automatically label my application sign-on line with a build number. This application is a plain vanilla C one without graphic UI; it is intended for command line, therefore it is a "simple" one.

The sign-on id is located in a "template" source file which is customized by CMake with a `configure_file()` command. Recently, I fancied to include a build number in this sign-on id. Consequently, the customization can no longer be statically done at CMake time, but everytime make is invoked.

To achieve that, there are two possibilities in CMake:

1. add_custom_target(), but it is triggered even when nothing else changes in the source tree which does not reflect the state of the tree;
2. add_custom_command(), which can be triggered only when the application (target) needs to be linked again.

I opted for the second solution and did not succeed.

Here is an extract of my *CMakeLists.txt*, the sign-on id being in file *ErrAux.c* (template in PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR, configured in PROJECT_BINARY_DIR):

```
add_executable(anathem ... ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ErrAux.c ...)

add_custom_command(TARGET anathem PRE_LINK
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"  "-DVERS=${PROJECT_VERSION}"
                                "-DSRC=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
                                "-DDST=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
                                -P "${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/BuildNumber.cmake"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    COMMENT "Numbering build"
    VERBATIM
)
```

This launches script *BuildNumber.cmake* just before the link step. It computes the next build number and customizes *ErrAux.c* with `configure_file()`.

It works fine, except ...

It happens late in the *make* sequence and the update to *ErrAux.c* goes unnoticed. The sign-on id in the executable contains the previous build number.

Next time I run *make*, *make* notices the generated *ErrAux.c* is younger than its object module and causes it to be compiled again, which in turn causes a link which triggers a build number update. This happens even if no other file has changed and this loop can't be broken. This is clearly shown in the compiling log:

```
Scanning dependencies of target anathem
[ 13%] Building C object AnaThem/CMakeFiles/anathem.dir/ErrAux.c.o
[ 14%] Linking C executable anathem
Numbering build
3.0.0-45
[ 36%] Built target anathem
```

The crux seems to be that `add_custom_command(TARGET ...)` can't specify an output file like  `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ...)` does. But this latter form can't be triggered in PRE_LINK mode.

As a workaround, I forced a compilation to "refresh" the object module with:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET anathem PRE_LINK
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"  "-DVERS=${PROJECT_VERSION}"
                                "-DSRC=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
                                "-DDST=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
                                -P "${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/BuildNumber.cmake"
    COMMAND echo "Numbering"
    COMMAND echo "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" "\$(C_DEFINES)" "\$(C_INCLUDES)" "\$(C_FLAGS)" -c "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ErrAux.c"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" "\$(C_DEFINES)" "\$(C_INCLUDES)" "\$(C_FLAGS)" -c "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ErrAux.c"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    COMMENT "Numbering build"
    VERBATIM
)
```

An explicit compilation is forced after sign-on id customization. It mimics what is found in the various *Makefile*'s and my not be safe for production. It's a cheat trick on both *CMake* and *make*.

UPDATE: Option `-c` is required to postpone link step until the final application liniking process.

<del>This addition creates havoc in the link, as shown by the log, where you see a double compilation (the standard *make* one and the `add_custom_command()` one):</del>

```
Scanning dependencies of target anathem
[ 13%] Building C object AnaThem/CMakeFiles/anathem.dir/ErrAux.c.o
[ 14%] Linking C executable anathem
Numbering build
3.0.0-47
Numbering
/usr/bin/cc -DANA_DEBUG=1 -I/home/prog/projects/AnaLLysis/build/AnaThem -I/home/prog/projects/AnaLLysis/AnaThem -g /home/prog/projects/AnaLLysis/build/AnaThem/ErrAux.c
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
AnaThem/CMakeFiles/anathem.dir/build.make:798: recipe for target 'AnaThem/anathem' failed
make[2]: *** [AnaThem/anathem] Error 1
```

<del>If I force a full recompilation, to make sure all sources are compiled, *main.c* included, I get the same error on `main`.

The only logical explanation is my manual C invocation is faulty and somehow destroys vital information. I checked with *readelf* that `main` is still in the symbol table for *main.c.o* and that it is still taken into account by the link step (from file *link.txt*).</del>

UPDATE: Even with the correct link, I'm still experiencing the infinite loop syndrom. The generated application still has its sign-on id lagging behind the actual build counter.

**Can someone give me a clue for the right direction?**

*FYI I'm quite new to CMake, so I may do things really wrong. Don't hesitate to criticize my mistakes.*

Comment: See also [Force CMake to generate configure_file target every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057208/force-cmake-to-generate-configure-file-target-every-build) for a discussion on the topic.

Comment: @florian Thanks for the link, but my use case is different: I increment a number when link is needed, which will always be different. This is not the same as retrieving a tag from a VCS. So the question is: how to feed back the link event into the compilation phase of make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the solution is to put the generated module where *make* expects to find it. *CMake* organizes the build tree in a non-trivial way.

The shortcomming in my added compilation in `add_custom_command()` was to believe that by default the binary will be stored in the "usual" *CMake* locations. Since I forge manually my compiler command, this is not the case.

I found the module in the source directory, which is a consequence of the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option, with name *ErrAux.o* and not *ErrAux.c.o*.

To obtain the correct behavior, I force an output location with:

```
-o "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/anathem.dir/ErrAux.c.o"
```

Now, when I run *make* again, nothing happens since nothing changed.

*Side question*

To make the solution portable (if needed), are there CMake variables for *CMakeFiles* and *anathem.dir* directories? Or in the latter case, for the current target as "anathem" as the target name in `add_custom_command()`?