# In CMake how do I create a file needed at configure time?

Tags: cmake, code-generation, configure

**Edit:** my question targets the early **configure** stage where CMake input files are still being parsed and thus have to be present before `include()` is being called. So the answer found here: [Force CMake to generate configure_file target every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057208/) does *not* solve my problem since it generates files *after* `include()` statements have been interpreted.

---

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that **includes** a file which is generated in the *configure* stage:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "my-generator -o generated.cmake")
include(generated.cmake)
```

Apart from the fact that this approach doesn't feel right (not to say elegant) I now need to re-generate that file *before every build* (`my-generator` produces output that incorporates the current time).

My assumption is that I can't use `add_custom_command()` or `add_custom_target()` because the file would be generated at compile time but needed in the configure-step.

[This](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/How-to-force-the-configure-step-to-start-over-td5698661.html) very old post suggests to `touch` the input file so I did this:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND "my-generator -o generated.cmake"
    COMMAND cmake -E touch "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}")
```

.. which does not produce errors but calling `make` multiple times won't run the configure step more than once.

What do I do wrong? Is there a better approach?

Comment: That's not how you use CMake. I am glad, that it does not work, as it would lead to curious (elegant?) CMake project, nobody would understand.

Comment: I admit this is abusing CMake principles. Maybe there is another way to accomplish the need to create variables (e.g. a timestamp) used in CMake commands  or variables like `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME`. I don't know any.