# In cmake, include arbitrary build-time information in/with the distributed executable

Tags: cmake

When using `cmake`, we wish for our distibutable files to contain some information about the release itself (such as a `git` tag or commit point). This is so we can basically tell from the installed package alone what release it is.

In other words, we're looking for something like the output of `git show | head -1`:

```
commit 695ec2ceca0854...blahblahblah
```

Our `cmake` files are fairly simple, consisting of:

```
add_executable(exename main.cpp functions.cpp functions.h)
```

How do we configure `CMakeLists.txt` to both generate this information *and* include it in the packaging for the project.

This could be baked in to the executable as a file with one string object like:

```
char *x = "XYZZY-commit 695ec2ceca0854...blahblahblah";
```

so that we can run `strings` on the executable to get the information.

It could also be a totally separate file like `commitpoint.txt` which is packaged and shipped with the executable.

Or, if anyone has a *better* way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

What I'd prefer to *avoid* is something that requires manual intervention when building, such as maintaining a module with the information hard-coded into it and stored in `git` itself. I'm looking for something that's fully automated.

Comment: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/cmake/modules/GenerateVersionFromCVS.cmake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cmake ships with a [find module for git](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGit.html) that can be used like this

```
find_package(Git)

if(Git_FOUND)
    execute_process(COMMAND "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" log --pretty=format:%h -n 1
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE commit_sha1
        ERROR_QUIET OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
else()
    set(commit_sha1 "Unknown")
endif()
```

where git arguments and the working directory could obviously be adjusted to your needs. The variable storing the desired info can now be used when configuring a file,

```
configure_file(version.cpp.in version.cpp)
```

where `version.cpp.in` contains

```
const char *gitInfo = "@commit_sha1@";
```

The generated `version.cpp` will be created in the build directory, and is included into the executable by

```
add_executable(exename ... ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp)
```

Comment: `configure_file` works at configuration time.  A git pull could change the commit without requiring CMake to rerun.  `add_custom_command` and/or `add_custom_target` with the found Git executable might work better.

Comment: Good point! I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3780667) question on the identical problem with svn repository info, where a solution for generating this info at build time is proposed.